# T-SQL with external script execution for in-database R integration

Tags: r, enterprise, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to convert a scaleR script into T-SQL (with external_script execution) for in-database R analytics in SQL Server. The scaleR script that I'm working with is on the [DeepDive Data Science Tutorial on Fraud data by MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt637368.aspx). 
All my data is in SQL Server now (from the tutorial), and all I want to do is query this table to get summary using the `rxSummary` scaleR function (in-database).
This is my attempt:

```
exec sp_execute_external_script 
@language = N'R', 
@script = N' 
sumOut <- rxSummary( 
formula = ~gender + balance + numTrans + numIntlTrans + creditLine, 
data = ccFraud 
) 
', 
@input_data_1 = N'select * from [DeepDive].[db_datareader].[ccFraudSmall]', 
@input_data_1_name = N'ccFraud', 
@output_data_1_name = N'summary' 
with result sets ((summary varchar(max) not null));
```

But this throws an error:

> ```
> STDOUT message(s) from external script: 
> Rows Read: 10000, Total Rows Processed: 10000, Total Chunk Time: Less than .001 seconds 
> Computation time: 0.000 seconds. 
> Msg 11536, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 
> EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 1 result set(s), but the statement only sent 0 result set(s) at run time.
> ```

Any idea how to deal with this?

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, there is a mismatch between the R script and SQL parameter definitions. The `output_data_1_name` parameter value specifies the name of the R dataframe that is being returned from R to SQL Server. But there is no value assigned to `summary` in the R script. Hence you are getting a 0 results error. See [sp_execute_external_script document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604368.aspx) for description and example.

If you are just trying to display the summary as messages, then you can add `print(sumOut)` to the R script.

If you want to return data to SQL Server, you would need to build an R dataframe and assign to the `output_1_data`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked to display the summary results. But when I want to save Summary to SQL Server, I tried adding `summary <- data.frame(sumOut)` to the R Script, it throws an error that rxSummary cannot be coerced to a data frame.

Comment: Are you trying to store the rxSummary object as a binary in SQL Server? Try using `summary <- serialize(sumOut, NULL);`

Comment: This is my code now: 
`@script = N'
    sumOut <- rxSummary(
         formula = ~gender + balance + numTrans + numIntlTrans + creditLine, 
         data = ccFraud
         )
    print(sumOut)
    summary <- serialize(sumOut, NULL);
    ',

 @input_data_1 = N'select * from [DeepDive].[db_datareader].[ccFraud10]',

 @input_data_1_name = N'ccFraud',
 @output_data_1_name = N'summary'
 with result sets ((summary varbinary(max) not null));`

Shows this error:  _The output dataset must be of type data frame; consider using data.frame() to convert it._

Comment: Also still shows this error: _EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 1 result set(s), but the statement only sent 0 result set(s) at run time._

Comment: Refer to the [Train and Save a Model using T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt683485.aspx) tutorial for an example of how to store a serialized R object to SQL Server table